# Equivalent to log4j in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, log4j

I am relatively new to Visual Basic. 
When it comes to logging, in Java I use log4j for logging. 
What is the equivalent in Visual Basic and can you please guide me to a good tutorial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [Log4Net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net):

That's a near-1:1 port of log4j, and so should be very familiar to you. However, what I really recommend for logging in most .NET apps is to simply use the [`Trace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.trace.aspx) class that's already built into the framework.

Comment: Great. The Trace class - can you specify which file to write to, or is it that it is going to end up somewhere in the Roaming folder?

Comment: Yes, the Trace class can write anywhere you want it to (including the console, visual studio debug window, network, syslogd, database, etc) by attaching different TraceListeners. For files, you would create a [TextWriterTraceListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.textwritertracelistener.aspx) with the right filename or stream prepared.